# time and volume prediction

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am learning ML and did some basic model training on colab. Right now I wanted to train a model which can predict time and volume. Here's the scenario:

I have a database with N number of users (consider user_id), and then each user has some job to do (consider this job_no). Every job has a time_taken field (which is in minutes) and a quantity field (consider this volume).

Now I wanted to train a model, which can predict time_taken and quantity for a given job of a given user. Let's say I wanted to predict time_taken and quantity for user-1, job-2.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with the help of some examples or reference links

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad, based on my understanding of your problem I would direct you to following two options

1. A simple solution, calculate median value of time and volume for each combination of user_id and job_id and use it as prediction to make prediction for existing user_id and job_id combination
2. Use regression, in my opinion your data is not suitable for this case as userid is not related in anyway related to time or volume so it is hard for regression model to find any meaningful relation, (in other word any user_id could have be assigned to any user and new user's will also be assigned any user_id) so you may want to find some more data about the user like, age, weight etc. which has some relation with the output.
   For job_id you can convert it to on hot encoded category and use as features for regression model like linear regression.
   Note: in case of user_id if you want to use the model with to predict only for users in the training dataset then model may find some complex relation there too